# Do I need to check, if user is authenticated when using passport.authenticate()?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

Using JWT auth in Passport.js. I have an endpoint, where I need to ensure, if user is authenticated

```js
router.get('/', passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false}), (req, res) => {
    if (!req.user) return res.status(401).send()
    return res.json(memberController.findFamilyMembers(req.user))
})
```

Is this if statement unnecessary? My strategy:

```
passport.use(new JwtStrategy({
    jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
    secretOrKey: process.env.JWT_SECRET
}, (jwtPayload, done) => {
    return FamilyController.familyFindOneById(jwtPayload.sub)
        .then((user) => {
            if (!user) {
                return done("User not found!", false)
            }
            else {
                return done(null, user)
            }
        })
}))
```